# NullPointerException when subscribing to Observable in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I want to subscribe to an observable in my unit test. This is my code:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: AddressSearchViewModel

private lateinit var ioScheduler: TestScheduler
private lateinit var scheduler: TestScheduler

private lateinit var requestHelper: RequestHelper

@Test
fun testAutoComplete2Chars() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    requestHelper = RequestHelper(createConfiguration())

    ioScheduler = Schedulers.test()
    scheduler = Schedulers.test()

    val country = getCountry("NL")
    createViewModel(country)

    viewModel.predict("Br")

////// Error on this line!!
    viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable.subscribe(predictionsObserver)

    ioScheduler.triggerActions()
    scheduler.triggerActions()

    verify(predictionsObserver, times(1)).onNext(viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable.value)
    assertEquals(0, viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable.value?.size ?: 0)
}

private fun createViewModel(country: Country) {
    viewModel = AddressSearchViewModel(country)
    viewModel.ioScheduler = ioScheduler
    viewModel.scheduler = scheduler
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at rx.Subscriber.isUnsubscribed(Subscriber.java:108)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10358)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
at com.takeaway.android.core.view_model.AddressSearchViewModelTest.testAutoComplete2Chars(AddressSearchViewModelTest.kt:529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

I can not figure out what is wrong with my code. Can anybody help? I can confirm that `viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable` is not null.

Comment: `viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable` is not set in your `createViewModel()` and ends up being `null` indeed

Comment: @shkschneider No, it is actually set

Comment: maybe use `@Override public void setUp() throws Exception {super.setUp(); /* ... */}` or annotation `@Before` in order to have things setup before any test runs? maybe, use `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` instead of the jUnit runner for unit tests, when accessing views?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I don't need accessing views, it's a viewmodel test

Answer (score 0):

I am late with the answer but it may help somebody.

The result of `viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable` is null so when you call subscribe it just throws NPE.

Instead you need to stub the result of this method. To be able to use stubs you need to make your ViewModel a mock. You need to `spy` on it. So this line will change like this

```
viewModel = AddressSearchViewModel(country) // before
viewModel = spy(AddressSearchViewModel(country)) //after
```

after that you can stub the desired behavior like so

```
`when`(viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable).thenReturn(Observable.just(fakeExpectedResponse))
```

or you can also test error or empty cases like so

```
`when`(viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable).thenReturn(Observable.empty()) 
`when`(viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable).thenReturn(Observable.error(expectedException))
```

This stub method should go before the "real" call. So first you tell your mock ViewModel what to do and then invoke the method.

```
viewModel.predictionNominatimsObservable.subscribe(predictionsObserver)
```